# TypeError: Cannot unpack non-iterrable NoneType object Zbar Raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, zbar

I do know this have been asked before but i still cant get it to work on my code... I'm trying to make my raspberry pi a QRcode lector for a school project and when I run my code

```
from pyzbar import pyzbar
import argparse
import cv2

#code
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="chemin de l'image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

#load l'image
image=cv2.imread(args["image"])

#trouver lesQR/barcode dans l'image puisles decoder
barcodes=pyzbar.decode(image)

#loop barcode
for barcode in barcodes:
    #extraire les box des coins et faire un carre rouge autour du
    #barcode reconnu
    (x,y,w,h)=barcode.rect
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255), 2)

    #barcode est un byte donc besoin convertir en string en premier
    barcodeData=barcode.data.decode("utf=8")
    barcodeType=barcode.type

    #dessiner data barcode et ecrire sur image
    text="{}({})".format(barcodeData,barcodeType)
    cv2.putText(image,text,(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, (0,0,255),2)

    print("[INFO] {} code, contenu: {}".format(barcodeType,barcodeData))

#montrer output
cv2.imshow("Image",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but when I run "python barcode_scanner_image.py --image test.png", all i get is an error saying

```
       File "barcode_scanner_image.py", line 16, in <module>
              barcodes=pyzbar.decode(image)
       File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 181, in decode
              pixels, width, height = _pixel_data(image)
       File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py", line 147, in _pixel_data
              pixels, width, height = image
TypeError: Cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

please help

Comment: `NoneType` means you get `None` from some function - probably `image` is `None` - so you can't do `pixels, width, height = None`. Use `print()` to check values in variables

Comment: if you use wrong path to file then `imread()` doesn't show error but it returns `None` and you have to check `if image:` or `if image is not None:`. Try to use `/full/path/to/image.jpg`

Comment: @furas it doesnt work either, i changed the code and it still doesnt work

Comment: do you get the same error or different ? If different then it works but you have other mistakes in code.

Comment: if you have the same error then check what you get with `print(image)`. If it display `None` then you still have wrong path to image or file is not image.

Answer (score 1):

So I don't have the complete answer - but one of the commenters here was on the right track.

if you use the actual path image = cv2.imread('/home/pi/foo/bar')

it works (or at least did for me).

Hope this helps!